# map filter and mutate across columns

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

I want to calculate the proportion of a variable in subgroups compared to the proportion of the whole dataset. The subgroups are based on binary columns. I want to filter the dataframe for each column, count the grouping variable and calculate the proportions. To compare the proportions, I calculate an index value which is 100*prop_subgroup/prop_overall.
I tried and failed to do this with map. Below is a for-loop and a lot of detours to achieve this, and I´m looking for some help to clean up this code and solve this "the tidyverse way". Thank you!

```
data <- data.frame(group = sample(c(LETTERS[1:6], NA), 1000, T), 
               v1 = sample(c(0, 1, NA), 1000, T),  
               v2 = sample(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, NA), 1000, T),  
               v3 = sample(c(0, 1, NA), 1000, T, prob = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.9)),
               v4 = sample(c(0, 1, NA), 1000, T, prob = c(0.8, 0.1, 0.1)),
               v5 = sample(c("a", 1, NA), 1000, T, prob = c(0.8, 0.1, 0.1)))
```

Calculate the prop.table

```
result <- data %>% count(group) %>% na.omit() %>% transmute(group = group, prop = n/sum(n))
```

Select binary columns

```
data_binary <- data %>% select(where(is.numeric)) %>% 
  select(where(function(x) {max(x, na.rm = T) == 1})) %>% 
  bind_cols(data %>% select(group), .)
```

Very ugly peace of code to calculate the frequencies for each group. Left join because some subgroups do not contain all grouping variables. The key peace I failed to do with map is the filtering based on one column and count of another column applied to all binary columns.

```
for(i in 2:ncol(data_binary)){
  name <- names(data_binary)[i]
  result <- left_join(result, data_binary %>% filter(.[[i]] == 1) %>% count(group) %>% 
                      na.omit() %>% transmute(group = group, "{{name}}_index" := n/sum(n)))
}
```

Calculate index based on the frequencies

```
index <- bind_cols(result %>% select(group),
  result %>% transmute_at(vars(-c("prop", "group")), function(x) {100 * x / result$prop}))
```

Result

```
  group "v1"_index "v3"_index "v4"_index
1     A   79.90019   16.21418   60.54443
2     B   91.31450   97.28507   87.45307
3     C  114.26996  122.50712   95.30142
4     D   96.63614  175.24198  109.06017
5     E  100.08550  116.05938  126.39978
6     F  116.70123   62.55683  116.79493
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can accomplish this with a group_by, summarize to get counts and group_by, mutate to calculate fractions.  However, I don't produce the same result so perhaps I don't understand exactly how you want to calculate the fractions (sum only the ones?)

```r
data <- data.frame(group = sample(c(LETTERS[1:6], NA), 1000, T), 
                   v1 = sample(c(0, 1, NA), 1000, T),  
                   v2 = sample(c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, NA), 1000, T),  
                   v3 = sample(c(0, 1, NA), 1000, T, prob = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.9)),
                   v4 = sample(c(0, 1, NA), 1000, T, prob = c(0.8, 0.1, 0.1)),
                   v5 = sample(c("a", 1, NA), 1000, T, prob = c(0.8, 0.1, 0.1)))

library(tidyverse)

# counts and fractions for each combination of group and variable
data_long <- data %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  # select only binary
  select(group, where(~max(., na.rm = TRUE) == 1)) %>%
  # pivot and calculate sums and fractions
  pivot_longer(-group) %>%
  drop_na(value) %>%
  group_by(group, name) %>% summarize(count = sum(value), .groups = "drop") %>%
  group_by(group) %>% mutate(fraction = count / sum(count))
print(data_long)
#> # A tibble: 21 x 4
#> # Groups:   group [7]
#>    group name  count fraction
#>    <chr> <chr> <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 A     v1       61   0.693 
#>  2 A     v3        7   0.0795
#>  3 A     v4       20   0.227 
#>  4 B     v1       54   0.659 
#>  5 B     v3       10   0.122 
#>  6 B     v4       18   0.220 
#>  7 C     v1       45   0.75  
#>  8 C     v3        4   0.0667
#>  9 C     v4       11   0.183 
#> 10 D     v1       48   0.716 
#> # ... with 11 more rows

# pivot wider on fractions to get output in desired form
data_wide <- data_long %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = group, values_from = fraction)
print(data_wide)
#> # A tibble: 7 x 4
#> # Groups:   group [7]
#>   group    v1     v3    v4
#>   <chr> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 A     0.693 0.0795 0.227
#> 2 B     0.659 0.122  0.220
#> 3 C     0.75  0.0667 0.183
#> 4 D     0.716 0.0896 0.194
#> 5 E     0.707 0.0690 0.224
#> 6 F     0.677 0.154  0.169
#> 7 <NA>  0.725 0.0980 0.176
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>